# LUA - Is possible to get values of an index in a multidimensional table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

It is possible to get/return multiple values of an index in a multidimensional array/table?
I have tried lots of methods but none seem to work or at least IDK how to implement them since I'm new to Lua.

This is what I have done or got so far, my table looks like this:

```
data = {
   ["oranges"] = {
      ["price"] = {
         "0.23",
      },
      ["location"] = {
         ["nearest"] = {
            "Russia",
            "United States",
         },
         ["farthest"] = {
            "Brazil",
            "Australia",
         },
      },
   },
   -- More...
}
```

What I want from that is all values from let's say `["nearest"]`
The function I'm working with is a mess but well:

```
function getNearestLocation(data)
   for k, v in pairs(data) do
      if v == "oranges"
      then
         -- Whatever I do here can't get it to work.
         for data, subdata in pairs({v}) do
            if subdata == "location"
            then
               return subdata["nearest"]
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

It is possible then to get `{"Russia","United States"}` for example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you know how to index a table. so all you need to realize is that you have tables in tables. `data.oranges` is a table, which you can index as well, `data.oranges.location` is also a table, index it... `data.oranges.location.nearest` is the table you're looking for.   please read the Lua Reference Manual

Comment: Yeah, I have learned that day that I could also access/iterate tables using dots, useful for better readability. The problem was that I got stuck for using the wrong idea that I could access those tables in the same way I'm used to with ```arrays()``` on PHP. Thanks for bringing more light to the topic, I found it very useful. Have nice time @Piglet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table you seek is `data["orange"]["location"]["nearest"]`.

If you need a function, use

```
function getNearestLocation(data)
   return data["orange"]["location"]["nearest"]
end
```

Comment: Hi @lhf thank you so much for showing me how simple it is the solution. Have a great day or night and take care.